# C# Json Deserialization failing at first char in json string

Tags: c#, json, serialization, encoding, deserialization

I'm currently struggling as a lot of people before me on the problem with de-serializing a json string. Sadly I wasn't able to find anyhting quite like my Problem. I tried multiple solutions but got none to work.

After reverting a bit and cleaning up everything I got to the problem I'm facing now: Everytime I try to de-serialize a json string the DataContractSerializer  throws an exception while trying to read the string.

The exception occurs here:

```
    public static T DeserializeJSON<T>(string json)
    {
        T obj;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);

        return obj;
    }
```

In the line:

```
        obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
```

Which isn't that surprising because it's the Part where everything gets parsed and one would exspect the most potential for something going wrong.

So for testing purposes I made a dummy class to de-serialize into:

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonTestObject
{
    [DataMember]
    string name;
}
```

And tried to parse:

```
        JsonTestObject obj = new JsonTestObject();
        obj = JSONSerializer.DeserializeJSON<JsonTestObject>("{\"name\" : \"works\"}");
```

However even this simple test just won't work and throws the same exception I got with my first more complex tests:
"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" occured in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll .

Data on the first layer is invalid. Line 1 , position 1.

I tried multiple encodings but as to my knowledge this only can lead to problems when parsing something from and outer source e.g. a WebRequest.

And as I'm at the end of my knowledge I hope someone here can spot the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer` see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb412179(v=VS.110).aspx) for more info.

BTW I would recommend JSON.NET see this [link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) for more info.

Comment: Thanks so much for spotting that. Looks like I got a bit distracted from the simple errors. Well to whom hasn't that happened once in a while.

Everything works fine now. And regarding Json.NET thanks for this Info it looks really great an easy to use. But as this is for just a hobby project I think if I don't run into some major problems from now on I will still try to "reinvent the wheel" just because of learning purposes.